# REST streaming with configure amount of processing object - unloading memory

Tags: java, json, performance, jackson2

I implement rest streaming and for now all works fine, but I see one problem with my implementation, when sending big amount of heavy file. For example, when I send 10 files by 100 MB in memory I have 1GB. So my question is how to implement this in modern java or by iterator?

I receive `ObjectJson` as `InputStream` and I have method when I read `JSON` values and get `List` of my domain object:

```
List<DomainObject> jsonStreamToDomainObject(final InputStream stream) throws IOException {
    return objectMapper.readValue(stream, new TypeReference<List<DomainObject>>() {
    });
}
```

So I think the method should look like below. But I think should be better solution than `iterator` and also I dont know how to convert `Input stream` to `Iterator`:

```
Iterator<DomainObject> jsonStreamToDomainObject(final InputStream stream) throws IOException {
return someMagicWithInputStream(stream);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use Jackson To Stream Parse an Array of Json Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24835431/use-jackson-to-stream-parse-an-array-of-json-objects)

Comment: check this blog it will helpful to achieve iterator from inputstream https://www.geekality.net/2011/05/23/java-inputstream-line-iterator/