# Edit an inputstream and write it out as a stream without storing all of its contents into memory at any given time

Tags: java, json, stream, jackson, inputstream

I have a method that is receiving an InputStream of data in JSON format.  Using Jackson's ObjectMapper, I am able to convert the InputStream into a JsonNode that I can edit, like so:

```
JsonNode revisions = mapper.readTree(data);
```

From there, I am able to iterate through each element and make my changes.  In doing so, though, I am storing all the elements in a list and then converting the list to a Stream.  I would prefer to operate on each element one at a time from the InputStream, that way I don't have to store it all in memory.

Here's what I have:

```
public Stream<Revision> jsonToRevisionObjects(InputStream allData) throws IOException {
    // convert the InputStream to a JsonNode
    JsonNode revisions = mapper.readTree(allData);

    List<Revision> newRevisions = new ArrayList<>();
    for (JsonNode revision : revisions.get("results")) {
        // create Revision objects and add them to newRevisions
    }
    return newRevisions.stream();
}
```

This essentially defies the point of even using Stream since I'm storing all the new Revision objects into memory.  Instead, I'd like to read one element at a time and send it off to the stream before loading in the next element.  Is there a way of doing this?  Based on surrounding code, the input parameter will always be an InputStream (there lies the problem) and the return type will always be Stream.

this might be possible if I was able to convert an InputStream into a Stream and do the following:

```
return allDataStream.map(rev -> {
    // create Revision object
       });
```

but I'm not sure how to get to that point if it's a possibility.

Comment: I'm assuming that `allData` is a list of JSON objects, is that correct? I am wondering, in that case, if it is acceptable to read each object into memory one at a time, rather than the whole list

Comment: yes, which is what I'd like to do instead.  It would be easy if the data was coming in as a stream (then I could just use map), but I'm not sure what to do since it's coming in as an InputStream

Comment: I found the following response to a similar question, which may be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/a/31275144/3529744

Comment: "without storing data into memory" that's not possible, AFAIK you have to read a stream to know what's "inside" and "edit" it

Comment: ok sorry, not storing everything in memory. In other words, 1 element at a time.  I will update

Answer (score 0):

To use streaming reads, you must use `JsonParser`, either directly, or by passing it to `ObjectMapper`/`ObjectReader`. If so, you may read sub-trees as `JsonNode` if you want to.

To construct a `JsonParser` from `InputStream` is simple:

JsonParser p = mapper.getFactory().createParser(inputStream);

but operation after this varies; you can either read token-stream directly from `JsonParser`, or ask `ObjectMapper` or `ObjectReader` to read next "value" from stream. And then the structure of JSON data matters; you may need to advance parser's stream (`nextToken()`) if you want to avoid reading all the contents.

Comment: hmm, it'll take a bit of work but I'll try some things.  Do you know if there's a way to get chunks of json at a time?  As in.. I have a list of JSON objects and want to grab a full object at a time in that list (so let's say 3 key:value pairs).  I can keep iterating one at a time doing nextField and nextValue, but I'd prefer to just create an entire map at a time

Comment: @user2869231 not quite sure I understand your question here. Jackson has to decode parts of underlying JSON content to know what is what, and this is exposed as a `JsonToken` stream, traversable using `JsonParser.nextToken()` (and similar methods). With that you can do anything you want. At higher level, `ObjectReader`/`ObjectMapper` your choices are more limited, as they read sub-trees.